# Spring test profiles: how to load only related test context resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-test

This is my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host: localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port: 27017

spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/frontoffice
spring.datasource.username: frontoffice
spring.datasource.password: password
spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver

application.defaultLanguage: ca_ES
```

And this is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class GridFSTest {

    @Autowired
    private GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate;

    @Test
    public void storeFile() throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(TestResources.CompatibleMatch.CSV_DOCUMENT.getPath());
        InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path);

        this.gridFsTemplate.store(
          is,
          path.getFileName().toString(),
          "text/plain",
          null
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void getFile() {
        Path path = Paths.get(
          TestResources.CompatibleMatch.CSV_DOCUMENT.getPath()
        );

        GridFSFile gridFsFile = this.gridFsTemplate.findOne(
          Query.query(
            Criteria
              .where("filename")
              .is(path.getFileName().toString())
            )
          );
        assertEquals(path.getFileName().toString(), gridFsFile.getFilename());
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm only testing `spring-data-mongodb` related classes.

The point is that when I run this test, `Spring` is trying to load all resources, configuration which are not not related with my concrete test.

I'd like to load ONLY resources related with mongo, and remove the others.

Also, I'd like to have several `*.properties` file into my `src/test/resources`, one for each kind of context.

I know that exists `ActiveProfiles` anotation but, how could I annotate third-party library resources? `spring-data-mongodb` attemps to load its `@Configuration` classes, and I'm not able to change this behavior.

I hope I've explained so well.

Comment: have you seen the annotation `@ActiveProfiles({"test"})`?

Comment: But, how Could I annotate third-party library resources? `spring-data-mongodb` attemps to load its `@Configuration` classes, and I'm not able to change this behavior.

Comment: Have you looked at test slicing: https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4 ?

Comment: The beans that are defined in the `@Configuration` classes would then have to be annotated with either `@Profile("test")` or `@Profile("prod")` - does this make sense?

Comment: I don't know if `@Configuration` annotated classes of third-party libraries like `spring-data-mongodb` are annotated...

Comment: if we speaking about properties it will be parsed all but have been used only properties which required by spring-beans. If we speaking about spring beans you can use `@ContextConfiguration` and declare only mongo related classes which required for your test  - in this case will be using only mongo properties.